# NHibernate suddenly very slow - inexplicable behaviour

Tags: c#, performance, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4, dottrace

I know this is a popular issue and various solutions have been proposed to others, but mine is slightly different.

Firstly it started happening suddenly since two days ago and nothing has changed in the NHibernate layer to explain such a change in behaviour.

I used dotTrace and drill down to it and found that certain cached queries take up to 70 seconds to perform (i.e. a GetAllCountries() method that returns a list of country objects).

70 seconds is pretty insane for such a simple query that doesn't have external references.

dotTrace reveals that it called the CachedCountryService which should return the list immediately. Instead it eventually leads to the CountryService which performs the 70 second read.

The database is mySQL.

An attached image of the dotTrace report

[image: An attached image of the dotTrace report]

The Country object looks like this:

```
   public class CountryMapping : ClassMap<Country>
    {
        public CountryMapping()
        {
            Table("ma_tbl_country");

            Id(t => t.Id, "id");
            Map(t => t.Code, "code");
            Map(t => t.Name, "name");
            Map(t => t.Match, "`match`");

            References(t => t.RiskGroup).Column("RiskId");

            HasManyToMany(t => t.PaymentOptions)
                .Table("ma_tbl_country_payment_option")
                .ParentKeyColumn("country_id")
                .ChildKeyColumn("payment_option_id").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        }
    }
```

The Initializer doesn't affect the country object although Office and Account are used in anoher NHibernate query that performs really poorly (takes 30 seconds).

```
 public NHibernateInitializer()
        {
            base.
            ExtraConfiguration =
                t =>
                    t.Mappings(s => s.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<DAL.Mappings.OfficeMapping>().Conventions.Add(typeof(DisableLazyLoadConvention)))
                    .Mappings(s => s.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AccountMapping>().Conventions.Add(AutoImport.Never()));
        }
```

And the DefaultLazyConvention is part of an internal library that does this:

```
  public class DisableLazyLoadConvention : IHibernateMappingConvention, IConvention<IHibernateMappingInspector, IHibernateMappingInstance>, IConvention
  {
    public void Apply(IHibernateMappingInstance instance)
    {
      instance.Not.DefaultLazy();
    }
  }
```

UPDATE:

I added SQL level profiling and the results are buffling.

I have two different projects running the same almost code and I get 324 sql queries in the slow projects taking 100 seconds to run and then 324 IDENTICAL queries in the other project taking 1 second!

So I believe the problem is NHibernate configuration, rather than code because these two set of queries are identical using the same domain models. They're also using the same database with the same db user.

Comment: Do you have your NHibernate logging level set to "DEBUG"?  Try changing it to "WARN" or "ERROR".

Comment: I can see the image just fine.

Comment: I have it to ALL because I am trying to see the queries. Before it was on ERROR and it logged nothing. The queries don't fail, they just take forever. And it's only specific queries

Comment: Right click on image --> View image (at least in Firefox).

Comment: Not in Chrome, but hope that others can magnify it

Comment: Does `Country` have any collections that are marked `lazy="false"`?

Comment: No it doesn't. I've added the code for the Mapping of Country and the Initializer. Lazy loading is disabled on one object only

Comment: Can you post the code for `DisableLazyLoadConvention`?

Comment: Sure, I added it. All this started happening two days ago, I can't in the life of me figure out why, but it is either configuration related or some database issue? maybe foreign keys gone missing.. no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY got this resolved.

It wasn't NHibernate related! That's why it was so impossible to resolve.

The problem was caused by this package called Combres. It is installed via Nuget with a lot of dependencies. In one of my projects, one of the dependencies was slightly higher version than it expected.

When I uninstalled it and re-installed it, it put the correct DLL versions in place (the slightly older ones) and that made the project work lightning fast!

If anyone is ever caught in such a difficult problem, I hope this might help them to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

From your dotTrace screenshot, please notice that `InitializeNonLazyCollections` is taking almost all of the time.

The `DisableLazyLoadConvention` is being applied to more than just `Office`.  It is being applied to all `ClassMap`s in the same assembly as `OfficeMapping`.  Conventions are used to apply mappings in wide paintbrush strokes across your entire application.  For example, you can use them to say things like "Whenever you see a `DateTime` property whose name ends with 'Utc', map it using `.CustomType("UtcDateTime")`."

If you need to apply special mappings to just one class, do so in the `ClassMap` (for fluent mappings) or in an `IAutoMappingOverride` (for auto mapping).  If you want to change the mapping for every class, that's when you use conventions.

Remove `.Conventions.Add(typeof(DisableLazyLoadConvention))` from your NHibernate initialization code, and replace it with more targeted calls to `.Not.LazyLoad()` in `OfficeMapping`.

Comment: Very promising. Let me check

Comment: If I remove that convention then I get:
"method get_Id should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'" on all the entity classes in the system.

Comment: This line has the problem:
CurrentSessionContext.Bind(nHibernateContext.SessionFactory.OpenSession());

Comment: Yes.  In order for lazy loading to work (and you really want it to work - see [ayende's blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/4573/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it)), all public and protected members of your entities must be marked virtual.

Comment: See [Davy Brion's article explaining why everything must be virtual](http://thatextramile.be/blog/2009/03/must-everything-be-virtual-with-nhibernate/).

Comment: I'm afraid that can't be it. These domain objects are shared by other projects all of which have the same NHibernate configuation and do not exhibit these delays. Only my project does. Not only I cannot change them, but I am pretty sure it's not what's making my project different to the others that are performing well.

Comment: You have cold hard proof in the form of the above screenshot that `lazy="false"` is the source of your performance problems.  `GetAllCountries` takes 67.7 seconds, and  `InitializeNonLazyCollections` is 64.4 of that.  That's 95%!

Comment: But of course, you're quite right that if this initialization code is common to other projects, but the other projects don't have performance problems, then there must be something else that's different.  What's different must be the way they are executing their queries.

Comment: If you never ever allow the entities to load, then you could still get good performance out of this, but your NHibernate code would just be a sad shadow of what it could be.  I.e. - if you use a query like: `session.Query<Country>().Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Code, x.Name })`, where you tell NHibernate "only fetch these columns, nothing more", then you will be OK.  But you won't be able to do things like `country.RiskGroup.Name`, and you won't be able to make changes to the entity and save it, because you never actually loaded the entity.